# Drawing performance with multiple UIBezierPaths

Tags: xcode, swift, drawing, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have a drawing app which is currently made up of a main View Controller which holds 4 separate UIViews which simultaneously replicate the line drawn on the touched quadrant across the other 3 with some axis reversed to make the drawing symmetrical.
When using this method the drawing is smooth and you can see that there are lots of points being collected when the user moves their finger as the line follows their movements quite well.

The code at a high level looks like this:

```
MainViewController.swift

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch: UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    var p = CGPoint()

    if touch.view == quadrant1 {
        p = touch.locationInView(quadrant1)
        quadrant1.began(p)
        var p2 = CGPointMake(quadrant2.bounds.width - p.x, p.y)
        quadrant2.began(p2)
        var p3 = CGPointMake(p.x,quadrant3.bounds.height - p.y)
        quadrant3.began(p3)
        var p4 = CGPointMake(quadrant4.bounds.width - p.x, quadrant4.bounds.height - p.y)
        quadrant4.began(p4)
    } else if touch.view == quadrant2 {
    ...
```

Touches 'moved' and 'ended' call similar methods in each of the quadrants by doing the same calculations. The Quadrant files look like this:

```
Quadrant1,2,3,4.swift

// A counter to determine if there are enough points to make a quadcurve
var ctr = 0

// The path to stroke
var path = UIBezierPath()

// After the user lifts their finger and the line has been finished the same line is rendered to an image and the UIBezierPath is cleared to prevent performance degradation when lots of lines are on screen
var incrementalImage = UIImage()

// This array stores the points that make each line
var pts: [CGPoint] = []

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        incrementalImage.drawInRect(rect)
        path.stroke()
    }

func began (beganPoint: CGPoint) {
    ctr = 0
    var p = beganPoint
    pts.insert(beganPoint, atIndex: 0)
}

func moved(movedPoints: CGPoint) {
        var p = movedPoints
        ctr++
        pts.insert(movedPoints, atIndex: ctr)
        // This IF statement handles the quadcurve calculations
        if ctr == 3 {
            pts[2] = CGPointMake((pts[1].x + pts[3].x)/2.0, (pts[1].y + pts[3].y)/2.0);
            path.moveToPoint(pts[0])
            path.addQuadCurveToPoint(pts[2], controlPoint: pts[1])
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
            pts[0] = pts[2]
            pts[1] = pts[3]
            ctr = 1
        }
    }

    func ended (endPoint: CGPoint) {
        if ctr == 2 {
            path.moveToPoint(pts[0])
            path.addQuadCurveToPoint(pts[2], controlPoint: pts[1])
        }
        self.drawBitmap()
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        path.removeAllPoints()
    }

    func drawBitmap() {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        var rectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
        UIColor.clearColor().setFill()
        rectPath.fill()
        incrementalImage.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
        color.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
        incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

So the above approach actually worked very well and produce fairly smooth lines like so but the user was always locked into using 4 quadrants because they were separate UIView's:

[image]

---

After some thinking we decided to scrap the 4 separate UIView's and use a single view to handle the drawing which would allow an arbitrary number of lines to be drawn at a time giving the user more options (8 lines for example), and this is where things got tricky.

The MainViewController no longer handles the touches interaction methods, the new 'DrawingView' captures the gestures itself with a UILongPressGestureRecogniser.

```
func handleLongPressDrawing(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    var p = sender.locationInView(self)

    switch sender.state {
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
        self.began(p)
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
        self.moved(p)
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
        self.ended(p)
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

The methods now reference a new DrawingElement class to perform the symmetry calculations:

```
enum GridType {
    case ONE, TWO_1, TWO_2, TWO_3, TWO_4, THREE, FOUR_1, FOUR_2, FIVE, SIX_1, SIX_2, SEVEN, EIGHT_1, SIXTEEN
}

enum DrawingElementType {
    case PATH, POINT, CIRCLE
}

class DrawingElement: NSObject {

var points : [CGPoint] = []
private var drawingWidth : CGFloat!
private var drawingHeight : CGFloat!
private var gridType : GridType!
private var drawingElementType : DrawingElementType!

init(gridType : GridType, drawingWidth : CGFloat, drawingHeight : CGFloat) {
    self.gridType = gridType
    self.drawingWidth = drawingWidth
    self.drawingHeight = drawingHeight
    super.init()
}

func getPoints() -> [CGPoint] {
    return points
}

func addPoint(pointCG: CGPoint) {
    points.append(pointCG)
}

func getPoint(pos : Int) -> CGPoint {
    return points[pos]
}

func getDrawingWidth() -> CGFloat {
    return drawingWidth
}

func setDrawingWidth(w : CGFloat) {
    drawingWidth = w
}

func getDrawingWidthCG() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(drawingWidth)
}

func getDrawingHeight() -> CGFloat {
    return drawingHeight
}

func setDrawingHeight(h : CGFloat) {
    drawingHeight = h
}

func getDrawingHeightCG() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(drawingHeight)
}

func getPointCount() -> Int {
    return points.count
}

func getDrawingElementType() -> DrawingElementType {
    return drawingElementType
}

func setDrawingElementType(det : DrawingElementType) {
    drawingElementType = det
}

func getGridType() -> GridType {
    return gridType
}

func setGridType(gt : GridType) {
    gridType = gt
}

func smoothLinesPart1() {
    points[2] = CGPointMake((points[1].x + points[3].x)/2.0, (points[1].y + points[3].y)/2.0)
}

func smoothLinesMoveTo() -> CGPoint {
    return points[0]
}

func smoothLinesQuadCurve() -> (CGPoint, CGPoint) {
    return (points[2], points[1])
}

func smoothLinesReorderArray() {
    points[0] = points[2]
    points[1] = points[3]
}

func getCalculatedPoints(allPoints : [CGPoint]) -> [Int : [CGPoint]] {
    var newPoints = [CGPoint]()
    var numberOfPoints : Int!
    var temp : CGFloat!
    var x : CGFloat!
    var y : CGFloat!
    //println("Before Path points: \(allPoints)")
    var pathPoints = [Int() : [CGPoint]()]
        if(gridType == GridType.EIGHT_1) {
        numberOfPoints = 8
    } else if(gridType == GridType.ONE) {
        numberOfPoints = 1
    } else if(gridType == GridType.TWO_1) {
        numberOfPoints = 2
    } else if(gridType == GridType.FOUR_1) {
        numberOfPoints = 4
    }

    var firstTime = true
    for point in allPoints {
        x = point.x
        y = point.y

        if(gridType == GridType.EIGHT_1 || gridType == GridType.ONE || gridType == GridType.TWO_1 || gridType == GridType.FOUR_1) {

            if(firstTime) {
                for i in 1...numberOfPoints {
                    switch (i) {
                    case 5:
                        temp = y;
                        y = x;
                        x = temp;
                        pathPoints[4] = [CGPoint(x: x, y: y)]
                    case 1:

                        pathPoints[0] = [CGPoint(x: x, y: y)]
                        //println(" first point\(pathPoints[0])")
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pathPoints[1] = [CGPoint(x: (x - getDrawingWidthCG()) * -1, y: y)]
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        pathPoints[5] = [CGPoint(x: (x - getDrawingWidthCG()) * -1, y: y)]
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pathPoints[2] = [CGPoint(x: x, y: (y - getDrawingHeightCG()) * -1)]
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        pathPoints[6] = [CGPoint(x: x, y: (y - getDrawingHeightCG()) * -1)]
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        pathPoints[3] = [CGPoint(x: (x - getDrawingWidthCG()) * -1, y: (y - getDrawingHeightCG()) * -1)]
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        pathPoints[7] = [CGPoint(x: (x - getDrawingWidthCG()) * -1, y: (y - getDrawingHeightCG()) * -1)]
                        break;
                    default:
                        break
                        //newPoints.append(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
                    }

                }
                firstTime = false
            } else {

                for i in 1...numberOfPoints {
                    switch (i) {
                    case 5:
                        temp = y;
                        y = x;
                        x = temp;
                        pathPoints[4]?.append(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
                    case 1:

                        pathPoints[0]?.append(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
                        //println(" first point\(pathPoints[0])")
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pathPoints[1]?.append(CGPoint(x: (x - getDrawingWidthCG()) * -1, y: y))
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        pathPoints[5]?.append(CGPoint(x: (x - getDrawingWidthCG()) * -1, y: y))
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pathPoints[2]?.append(CGPoint(x: x, y: (y - getDrawingHeightCG()) * -1))
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        pathPoints[6]?.append(CGPoint(x: x, y: (y - getDrawingHeightCG()) * -1))
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        pathPoints[3]?.append(CGPoint(x: (x - getDrawingWidthCG()) * -1, y: (y - getDrawingHeightCG()) * -1))
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        pathPoints[7]?.append(CGPoint(x: (x - getDrawingWidthCG()) * -1, y: (y - getDrawingHeightCG()) * -1))
                        break;
                    default:
                        break
                        //newPoints.append(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And this is called at various parts of the DrawingViews interaction handlers:

```
var paths = [Int() : UIBezierPath()]

func began (beganPoint: CGPoint) {
    strokes = 0
    var p = beganPoint
        ctr = 0
        //pts.insert(beganPoint, atIndex: 0)
    drawingElement?.addPoint(beganPoint)
}

func moved(movedPoints: CGPoint) {
    strokes++
    var p = movedPoints
            ctr++
    drawingElement?.addPoint(movedPoints)
    if ctr == 3 {
        drawingElement?.smoothLinesPart1()
        path.moveToPoint(drawingElement!.smoothLinesMoveTo())
        path.addQuadCurveToPoint(drawingElement!.smoothLinesQuadCurve().0, controlPoint: drawingElement!.smoothLinesQuadCurve().1)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        drawingElement?.smoothLinesReorderArray()
        ctr = 1

    }

    var pointsArray : [CGPoint] = drawingElement!.getPoints()

    var calcArray = drawingElement?.getCalculatedPoints(pointsArray)

    let sortedCalcArray = sorted(calcArray!) { $0.0 < $1.0 }

    if pointsArray.count > 1 {
        for (pIndex, path) in sortedCalcArray {
            paths[pIndex] = UIBezierPath()
            for var i = 0; i < path.count; i++ {
                paths[pIndex]!.moveToPoint(path[i])
                if(i > 0) {
                    paths[pIndex]!.addLineToPoint(path[i-1])
                }
                self.setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        }
    }

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    for (index, path) in paths {

        path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound
        path.lineWidth = lineWidth

        color.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }

    color.setStroke()
    incrementalImage.drawInRect(rect)
}

}
```

I have a feeling that either 1) The iPhone does like drawing 4 or more paths within a single view at a time, or 2) the performance is degraded because of the number of loops that are running each time the user moves their finger. Here is what a similar line looks like with the above new code:

[image]

So after all of that I am wondering if anyone would be able to shed some light on why the new code draws so differently or what a better approach may be.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using the gesture recognizer, did you try capturing touches within the UIView subclass [directly](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:)? I suspect that the gesture recognizer may not be dispatching as many events, seeing as it is not really meant for tracking, but for long presses.

Comment: As a side note, it may be useful for performance to only draw one path and then apply appropriate transforms to each of the quadrants. That way you could use a single UIView with for example several CAShapeLayer sublayers (each transformed, but using the same path). You could also then apply similar transformations to the touches depending on in which part of the view they are.

Comment: Those are both very good points Henri, I will change over to the touches events first and see what difference that makes, then look at the CAShapeLayer idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after some trial and error I kept most of the code above, the only notable difference was that I constructed 4 separate UIBezierPaths and eliminated the for loop nested in the other for loop. That seemed to be causing the issue